# Is it possible to keep a WebRTC video call alive when the screen is locked on iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, webrtc

I am developing WebRTC video calling app on iOS and ideally I would like the call to be kept alive when the screen is locked or the user puts the app in the background. The app uses the [Socket.io library](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-swift).

Is it possible/allowed for me to keep both the web socket and peer connection alive when the screen is locked?

I know apple states that ["only specific app types are allowed to run in the background"](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW4), and specifically mentions apps that support VoIP as one of these. Based off this, I was wondering if WebRTC qualifies, and if so, how it would be done.

Comment: Hi. Did you come up with the answer?

Comment: No. I never found out.

Comment: What did you do?

Comment: Nothing. I didn't end up putting the feature in.

Comment: But the webrtc runs when the app is in background? For example you just browse through other apps

Comment: I don't think it did, as far as I remember. That might have been an issue with my app and not WebRTC itself however. I haven't been on the project for a while now so my memory isn't great.